# loop to move files not working

Tags: bash

I am having one of these mornings where nothing goes to plan.  I need to move files to a target directory by chunks of 1,000 at time

I wanted to loop thru my files like so

```
for i in `find . -name '*XML'`
   for((b=0; b<1000; b++))
   do
   mv $i targetdirect/
   done
done
```

But I get a "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done:" error.

What I am missing??

Comment: This loop would also (atttempt to) move each file to the target directory 1000 times. It does not move 1000 different files per call to `mv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `for` loop has no corresponding `do`  (You have two `done`, but only one `do`.)

Answer (score 3):

The second `for` loop is a syntax error.  Also you should double-quote `"$i"`.

What do you mean by moving 1000 files at a time?  Something like this perhaps?

```
find . -name '*.XML' -print0 | xargs -r0 -n 1000 mv -t targetdirect
```

The `-print0` and corresponding `xargs -0` are a GNU extension to handle arbitrary file names.  This works because the null character is an invalid character in file names on Unix; hence, it is safe to use as a delimiter between file names.  For regularly named files (no quotes, no newlines etc in the file names) this may seem paranoid, but it is well-documented practice and a [FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095).